# How to fix contact form 7 button's position?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7

[image]
Hi. I am using contact form 7 and need to fix the button's position on the right of the email input. As you see on the image it's a bit above of the email input while I need to make them equal vertically. How can this trouble be fixed?

Comment: it needs small CSS adjustmen. Share you URL here, then i will write an answer

Comment: I am working loacally. I've not added any css yet. Can you write  CSS adjustment here please? It's by default at the moment.

Comment: no, it is not possible without live URL. The problem is not related with default CSS of CF7. The problem is that your theme CSS affext CF7 fields. You can try this anyway:   .wpcf7-submit {padding-top:5px}